# Learning resources for Performance Testing and LoadRunner

Tags: learning, performance, load-testing

This question might be off-topic and/or Subjective but I am asking this question
because I could not fine any suitable answers via Google.

I am a Manual tester with knowledge of Java, SQL Server.
Recently i got an opportunity to work in performance testing (HP LoadRunner).
However there are not much resources around to learn loadrunner.

I am supposed to work alone and i couldn't find good tutorials on LoadRunner.
I read HP's tutorial but i don’t know what to do after that.

I will appreciate your advice on learning performance testing and LoadRunner.
If Possible please provide links to usable Books, sites and quizzes.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why a question asking for learning resources for a testing tool would be off-topic. Your question looks fine to me!

Comment: "Recently i got an opportunity to work in performance testing (HP LoadRunner). However there are not much resources around to learn loadrunner." Has your company contacted HP for LoadRunner training?

Comment: Good question - how did someone with no experience get assigned as the solo tester ? Will the person who put you into that role support you ?

Comment: I've assigned people into roles that were new to them at times. Each time, I provide a path for learning - through classes, seminars, mentoring, or combinations of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The person who has placed you in this role has an obligation to help you be successful.  The path to success in performance testing begins wih a confirmation and firming up of any foundation skills that are soft.  Next comes product training.  After that a period of internship.

Tools are only 5-12% of the skills you need to have.  Mind you it is a critical 5-12%, but if you lack the foundation skills and guidance provided through the mentoring process then your boss may as well be leading you into a room full of woodworking equipment and expecting a cherry pennsylvania highboy in three weeks when you lack even basic carpentry skills

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to performance testing. However, I am using Jmeter instead of LoadRunner.

But i learnt basics of LoadRunner from guru99 website and few more videos on youtube. I know manual guides are quite boring. But first, you have to identify websites were you can play and then prepare few scenarios. It will help to learn LoadRunner step by step. :)

I will share links as i find more.

Answer (score 1):

For learning about performance testing, browse around Scott Barbers site - this page is a great lst of articles and a free PDF - [here](http://www.perftestplus.com/pubs.htm)

Answer (score 1):

some more learning material can be found at below link:
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/hp-loadrunner-load-testing-tool-training-tutorials/

Comment: You really need to add more information to make this a useful answer, particularly with the age of the question and the number of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

[www.Guru99.com](http://www.guru99.com/loadrunner-tutorials.html) has some video tutorials on LoadRunner (LR). It is for beginners who want to know about LR basics.

It covers the following topics:

- Tutorial 1 - Introduction To Load Runner (7:56)
- Tutorial 2 - Introduction Mercury Tour Website (4:31)
- Tutorial 3 - Introduction Vuser,Controller , Analyzer (4:35)
- Tutorial 4 - Vuser Part 1 (4:46)
- Tutorial 5 - Vuser Part 2 (8:41)
- Tutorial 6 - Vuser Part 3 (2:16)
- Tutorial 7 - Transactions (2:27)
- Tutorial 8 - Playback (4:20)
- Tutorial 9 - Correlation Part 1 (6:59) (Must Watch)
- Tutorial 10 - Correlation Part 2 (1:06)
- Tutorial 11 - Correlation Part 3 (9:55)
- Tutorial 12 - Correlation Part 4 (2:35)
- Tutorial 13 - Parameterization (5:05)
- Tutorial 14 - Verification Checkpoints (5:42)
- Tutorial 15- Controller (6:45)
- Tutorial 16 - Analyzer

Comment: Welcome to SQA, tapan. Could you perhaps provide a small review of some of the video tutorials you've seen there, so people are more informed about what the resource is?